# When saving as CSV from Opensearch Discover, only some row of search results are saved

Tags: dashboard, opensearch

- OpenSearch 1.1.0 / Dashboard 1.1.0 / Docker ( Amazon Linux release 2 )

I did the following query in Discover

timestamp >= 1682504039854 and tags: level=ERROR
(timestamp field is of number type)

On browser, the data for dates greater than 1682504039854 is displayed normally ( 2000 rows ).
However, when I save it as a csv using the Reporting function, only the data with timestamp = 1682504039854 is saved ( 3 rows ).

Is there any way to save all the query results printed on the screen as a csv?

Answer (score 0):

> CSV reports have a non-configurable 10,000 row limit. They have no
> explicit size limit (e.g. in MB), but extremely large documents could
> cause report generation to fail with an out of memory error from the
> V8 JavaScript engine.

https://opensearch.org/docs/1.1/dashboards/reporting/

check if opensearch gets out of memory exception and try again.

I recommend you use logstash or [elasticdump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump) to download data from elasticsearch/opensearch.

An example:

```
elasticsearch-dump --input=http://localhost:9200/my_index --output=/path/my_index.csv --type=data
```

This command will export the data from the "`my_index`" index to a CSV file named "`my_index.csv`".

Comment: 1. the same problem is occurring even if I search for less than 100 results, so it is not a memory problem.
2. I can't use the tool you introduced because it is installed in a customer company with limited access from the external network, but I will try to test it. Thank you for introducing a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to navigate in to Dev tools and simply past and run tis script:

> ```
> PUT _template/example
> {
>   "index_patterns": ["settings_test*"],
>   "settings": {
>     "index.max_result_window": 99000
>   }
> }
> ```

Edit the number of rows you needed from 99.000 to ano other number.